# UIButton with image and text doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I searched for solution I saw couple similar posts here but I couldn't fin an answer.
I am trying to add an UIButton that sets with image (background colour only is good too)
and i want to add text on this image

so far this is my code :

```
        labelSorry.text = @"לא נמצאו תוצאות.";//add text
        //add button.
        Request =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIImage *requestimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"requestcontact_resize2.png"];
        Request.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 120, 320.0, 30.0);
        Request.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
       // Request.titleLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff);
        [Request setBackgroundImage:requestimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Request.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"requestcontact_resize2.png"];//see no image :( this is kidding me

      //  [Request setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 120, 320.0, 30.0)];///You can replace it with your own dimensions.
        label.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff);
        label.text = @"בקש פרטי איש קשר";
        [Request addSubview:label];

        //[Request setBackgroundColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x704c9f)];
        Request.titleLabel.text = @"בקש פרטי איש קשר";
        [Request addTarget:self action:@selector(requestDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [noResultsView addSubview:Request];
        [self.view addSubview:noResultsView];
```

I can see the background of the button , but I can't see any text on it :(
please maybe someone can enlighten me ?

as you can see I have tried various solutions(I put them in comment) but none worked.

P.S. I am not using xib.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `[button setImage:forState:]` and `[button setTitle:forState:]`. If you want set background image for button you should use `[button setBackgroundImage:forState:]`. Also, if you want, you can change position for image and title, for this use `[button setImageEdgeInsets:]` and `[btn setTitleEdgeInstes:]`.

Comment: But I do use :
       [Request setBackgroundImage:requestimg  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
something is wrong in here?

Comment: Oh I see , I didn't use "ForState" in the set title :) 
thanks you very much :)